# Global Web Application Parameter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I'm trying to set a parameter that's not allocated to a specific servlet but rather available globally throughout the web application. My current code gets the following as `null`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>example</param-name>
    <param-value>This is an example parameter value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and

```
getServletConfig().getInitParameter("example");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to change:

`getServletConfig().getInitParameter("example");`

**to:**

`getServletContext().getInitParameter("example");`